# Way to link two images together in Cloudinary

Tags: angularjs, json, cloudinary

I am trying to figure out an ideal way to link two images together. I have several hundred pictures with the tag `images`, but there a some images that have **before** and **after** pictures that I would like show side by side.

I am just unsure how to link images that have **before** and **after** together in either the JSON list on Cloudinary or using Angularjs Controller.

#### Example

```
{
  "public_id": "Images 2/A/LUND",
  "version":1463185535,
  "format":"jpg",
  "width":1299,
  "height":1732,
  "type":"upload",
  "created_at":"2016-05-14T00:25:35Z",
  "context":{
    "custom":{
      "alt":"Remodeling Stairs",
      "name":"Lund Before",
      "title":"Full Staircase Remodel"
    }
  }
},
{
  "public_id": "Images 2/A/LUND",
  "version":1463185535,
  "format":"jpg",
  "width":1299,
  "height":1732,
  "type":"upload",
  "created_at":"2016-05-14T00:25:35Z",
  "context":{
    "custom":{
      "alt":"Remodeling Stairs",
      "name":"Lund After",
      "title":"Full Staircase Remodel"
    }
  }
},
```

I am using Angularjs `ng-repeat` that will display the **after** pictures, but I have an `ng-click()` that will show a modal. In the modal I would like to show the **before** and the **after** pictures.

How could I attempt to link or bind the before picture with the after picture? Could this be done with Cloudinary tagging? Or a way to do this in an angular controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay the "After" image and offset it to start when the "Before" image ends. For example:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/<your_cloud_name>/image/upload/l_Images 2:A:LUND,x_1299/Images 2/A/LUND.jpg
```

I believe the following should work:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" cl-href="Images 2/A/LUND" overlay="Images 2/A/LUND" x="1299" />
```

Here's some more examples of combining multiple images into one:
http://cloudinary.com/cookbook/generate_your_photo_collage_online

Comment: Problem is that I have a couple hundred pictures. This might work with only a couple photos, but in my case it would not be a viable option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have hundreds of pictures you'd like to all be merged into one giant image, or do you have hundreds of couple of images where you'd like each couple (of before and after) to be merged into a single image?

Comment: I have hundreds of coupled images(before and after), i figured a work around by adding a `before` tag in the metadata with the other images URL. This way it's in the same image in the json. But open for a better alternative